# Saving a object which is a foreign key of another project in views.py in django

Tags: python, django

This is my views.py:

```
def handlerequest(request, id):
    order=Order.objects.get(id=id)
    items=order.orderitem_set.all()
    verify = Checksum.verify_checksum(response_dict, MERCHANT_KEY, checksum)
    if verify:
        if response_dict['RESPCODE'] == '01':
            order.complete=True
            order.save()
            for item in items:
                a=str(item.size)
                if a=="XS":
                    item.product.XS-=1
                    if item.product.XS<=0:
                        for s in item.product.size.all():
                            item.product.remove(1)
                        **#Save Product Here**      
    return render(request, 'handlerequest.html', {'response': response_dict,'order':order})
```

and this is my orderitem model:

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
```

What I want is that in my views.py when I am doing if a=="XS" after that I want to save the product(which has a different model).I tried several variations but got errors.How should I save the product after the if statement.

Comment: try to get product id using (`pid =  item.product.id`)and get actual product ( `p = Product.objects.get(id=pid)`) and edit value( `p.SX -=1` ) and save (`p.save()`)

Comment: Also, you should use an atomic transaction here to either save all or no entries: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly

Comment: Can you please briefly explain what this is for?